# Issue with angularjs $http delete method in firefox

Tags: angularjs

I have been searching in the google world but the solution not yet find. I am writing a method to delete a record in the ng-grid. This works great in IE and Chrome, but not working in firefox. It looks an exception of type aborting the operation but no exception in the console.

The following is my code block.

```
$scope.delete = function (row) {
              $scope.id = $scope.myData[row.rowIndex].EmpID;
              $http({
                  method: 'DELETE',
                  url: '/api/Values/Delete/',
                  ContentType: 'application/json',
                  params: {id1:$scope.id} // pass in data as strings
              }).success(function (data) {              
              }).error(function (data) {
              });
          }
```

Any one could you please guide me to solve the problem.

Comment: Does it hit the server?

Comment: No yar, it is the problem. If it hits the server means, no issue i think so :)